# Dynamic tabs: Adding them using a dataset and checking if they exist

Tags: c#, android, android-tabs, xamarin.android

I want to dynamically create a tab which is later populated with data from the dataset.
In my dataset I have a field called TabId. It used as a title and id which is later (on tab view) used to iterate through a dataset it fetches. Since in the future there might be more tabs and the client wants a solution that need as least of number of updates as possible i need to create them dynamically. But the problem is the dataset containing my tab data contains the tabId that is repeated for several times as you iterate through tables.

example:

```
Rec 1 TabId = first
Rec 2 TabId = first
Rec 3 TabId = first
Rec 4 TabId = first
Rec 5 TabId = first
Rec 6 TabId = first
Rec 7 TabId = first
Rec 8 TabId = Second
Rec 9 TabId = Second
Rec 10 TabId = Second
Rec 11 TabId = Third
Rec 12 TabId = Third
Rec 13 TabId = Third
```

and so on...

So basically I know I need to make a foreach loop using the TabId but I need only one tab per distinct\unique id. How would I iterate through my dataset and dispose of extra duplicates of my TabId so I can later use it to create my tabs on the fly.

My current (static) code:

```
intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Tab1));
intent.PutExtra("FormId", FormId);
intent.PutExtra("TabNum", TabId);
intent.PutExtra("EventNo", EventNo);
intent.PutExtra("Ticket", Ticket);
intent.PutExtra("DataSet", xml);
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

// Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost  
spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec(TabId); // unique per tab
spec.SetIndicator(TabId); // unique per tab
spec.SetContent(intent);
TabHost.AddTab(spec);
```

I hope I made myself clear enough. If any questions arise don't hesitate to ask. I will provide as much of information I can.

Comment: What is happening currently with the above? Is it adding just the one tab?

Comment: Currently it's static so it adds one tab. I need to add them dynamically according to what flies in from the dataset I get from a webservice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the distinct List using Linq and query the original datasource

```
var tabIDs = (from DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows
         select (Int32)dr["TabID"]).Distinct();
```

From a data set:

```
var tabIDs = (from DataRow dr in dataSet.Tables["tableName"].Rows
         select (Int32)dr["TabID"]).Distinct();
```

Then loop through your TabID's

```
foreach(Int32 tabID in tabIDs){

    spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec(tabID ); // unique per tab
    spec.SetIndicator(tabID ); // unique per tab
    spec.SetContent(intent);
    TabHost.AddTab(spec);

}
```

Comment: Ok that works for a DataTable but not on a DataSet :)
And I need to work with a dataset here. Still thanks for your help.

Comment: `System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable("TabIdTable");`
`dt.Columns.Add("TabId", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));`
`dt.Columns.Add("TabCaption", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));`
`System.Data.DataView Dv = _DataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;`
`System.Data.DataTable DtD = Dv.ToTable(true, "TabId", "TabCaption");`

Resolved using your advice and a bit of further searches based upon the insight you offered :)